# Mac OS battery cycle count

Tags: macos

Im under Yosemite OS X I got a new battery for my mac model a1398 mid 2012 retina, I charged the battery first time to 100% and drained it till it went to sleep mode to calibrate the battery, now I never let it go under 80% and plug the charger, most of time I use the charger but the thing is, I saw that my cycle count is 3 and it was 1 before, I don't understand how this happened? any idea?

Comment: Well if you let it go for example from 100% to 80% 10 times, that's two cycles. Plus when you drained it completely = 3 cycles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, if you discharge your battery halfway one day, then halfway again the next day, this counts as one cycle, not two.

In your case discharging to 80% it will take 5 times before a cycle is counted. (5x20% =100%) = 1 cycle.

Fully drained = 1 cycle.

Draining is not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

From Apple's [support note on battery cycles](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201585):

> A charge cycle means using all of the battery’s power, but that doesn’t necessarily mean a single charge. For instance, you could use your notebook for an hour or more one day, using half its charge, and then recharge it fully. If you did the same thing the next day, it would count as one charge cycle, not two, so it may take several days to complete a cycle.

So essentially, as long as you ever run the laptop unplugged *at all*, your cycle count will slowly increase.